# Detecting new lines in markdown string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, markdown

I am processing markdown files in my nodeJS application. So I have my markdown held as a string. I am trying to determine the difference between markdown like:

````
```Javascript
var code_block = something;
````

and

````
```
var code_block = something;
````

so I am approaching the issue like:

```
var language = markdown_string.substr(0, markdown_string.search("\n"));
console.log("Language: " + language);
```

So I am searching the string for the code between the  ```` ``` ```` and the newline, however, the `\n` isn't being found, so the string represents the rest of the file. if I search for  (blank space), then I get the var included, so my string doesn't seem to have anything detectable between the end of the backticks or the language and the next line.

Is this correct? Can you see any way I can pick up the rest of the top line after the triple backticks but before the var on the next line?

Comment: Are you sure the newline is actually in the string?  Seems like what you have should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that by splitting the string into chars, i.e. `var chars = markdown.split("");` and then looping through the next 15 values until `chars[i]` equals `\n` and using that as an index to substring the necessary part of the string. It works, but is a bit messy ...